# Laravel + Vue Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel application with Vue js and until a while ago it was working perfectly. Now when I go to any page that uses Vue js this error appears: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0".
When I reload the page by clearing the cache (Control + Shift + R on Mac OS) it works again, but when I update without this command the error appears again.

PS: I didn't do any package updates for both laravel and npm, it just stopped working out of nowhere.

[image]

Comment: could you post a page which consist of vuejs code

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the console:

```
JSON.parse(undefined)
```

Here is what you will get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

In other words, your app is attempting to parse `undefined`, which is not valid JSON.

There are two common causes for this. The first is that you may be referencing a non-existent property (or even a non-existent variable if not in strict mode).

```
window.foobar = '{"some":"data"}';
JSON.parse(window.foobarn)  // oops, misspelled!
```

The second common cause is failure to receive the JSON in the first place, which could be caused by client side scripts that ignore errors and send a request when they shouldn't.

Make sure both your server-side and client-side scripts are running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and lint them using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). This will give you pretty good confidence that there are no typos.

Sometime it is becaseu of this `let data = JSON.parse(this.response);` so try to change it to
`let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`

I really did was change `this.response` to `this.responseText`